# Entity Framework Code-First: Generate SQL script with 'Update-Database' produces XML error while parsing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Our project uses Entity Framework 6.0 with .NET 4.5, FAT-Client with Code-First approach.

We have about 20 migration-files (C# partial classes) generated automatically via the cmdlet `Add-Migration` in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console, and applied successfully via `Update-Database`.

Now, our client has an integration database that has around 10 migrations applied already, and we need to apply the remaining 10 migrations now. We used `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:<migration10>` in order to produce a SQL script for the remaining migrations. In this case – and also when using `SourceMigration:$InitialDatabase` – the following error is displayed:

```
[...]
Applying explicit migration: 201609141617112_HostAufbauIdentifier.
Applying explicit migration: 201609141622583_RemPerStaWe.
System.Xml.XmlException: 'SoftwareAuftrag_Auftrag' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1943, position 92.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowExpectingWhitespace(Int32 pos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Edm.ModelCompressor.Decompress(Byte[] bytes)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.GetModel(Func`2 modelAccessor)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.GetTargetModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate(String sourceMigration, String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScriptUpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScriptUpdate(String sourceMigration, String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

In the file that causes trouble, here `201609141622583_RemPerStaWe`, absolutely nothing is done with anything that has a name of `SoftwareAuftrag` or alike. This stuff is done in previous migrations, and there, I also don't see any problem at all.

I tried attaching the debugger via code, but I don't know where to set a break point. The option to 'break when an exception occurs' doesn't seem to trigger a break in this case. Maybe another sub-process is started from the package manager.

I have no clue how I could break down the problem, and we lose a ton of time on this. Hopefully someone has a hint on this. ;)

### UPDATE

I systematically deleted individual migration files until I found exactly 3 that in combination cause the error. But when I uncomment everything in `up` and `down` the error persists. When deleting the whole 3 migration files, the error is gone. How does that make sense? Problems with resource files? I don't know...

Answer (score 15):

I normally use a command like:

```
Update-Database -Script 
       -SourceMigration:"201502201618119_Migrations17"   
       -TargetMigration:"201503031134340_Migrations18"
```

and then run the resultant script on the server. `SourceMigration` is the last entry in the `__MigrationHistory` table on the server.

The other 'trick' I use with migration problems is to delete the migration scripts that have not been applied to the server and then run the `Add-migration` again. It may be that there is a conflict between two of the migrations that is causing this. Do this rather then tweaking the individual scripts.

UPDATE:
The timestamp in the above is not required. For example:
`SourceMigration:"Migrations17"` is all that is required.

Comment: The problem is that no script gets generated because of the mentioned XML error. I don't know what XML this is anyway. I found that for every migration, a .RESX file exists that stores some hash of the model. Maybe that causes trouble?

Comment: Thanks! Our situation is that there are two DB instances, DEV and INT. The former already has all migrations applied (at the time they were applied no error came up), while the latter is at migration #10. So removing individual scripts may work for INT, but would mean that we have to mess with DEV's "__MigrationHistory" table. We probably have to do this, but it would be much more calming if we actually understand the reason for the above error, also for future situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your post if I think right: you have applied the migration to the database by **project management console or command tool** than you have not need to migrate it again, automatically.

If I'm not mistaken, just cancel it at last step while publishing or running out

**1- Open the file**

> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets

**2- Delete the related node**

```
<GenerateEFSQLScripts
  Condition="'$(_IsAspNetCoreProject)' == 'true' And 

'$(IsGenerateEFSQLScriptsDisabled)' != 'true' And @(EfMigrations) != ''"
      ProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
      EFPublishDirectory="$(_EFPublishDirectory)"
      EFSQLScriptsFolderName="$(EFSQLScriptsFolderName)"
      EFMigrations="@(EFMigrations)"
      EFMigrationsAdditionalArgs="$(EFMigrationsAdditionalArgs)">
      <Output TaskParameter="EFSQLScripts" ItemName="_EFSQLScripts" />
    </GenerateEFSQLScripts>
```

It is the case that i have faced while *publishing* **Asp.Net core Web Api** project to azure